# Sendgrid PHP API - How do I authorize my email as a sender?

Tags: php, phpmailer, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

Thank you in advance for any help! I am moving from phpMailer to Sendgrid PHP APi.  I have my first test php script working AWESOME and it is sending.

However, my question is this. In phpMailer I had to authorize it to send from my chosen email (enter in server, email, and password). However, in the sendgrid API I don't see a place for that. In fact, I was able to send a test from "test@example.com" a domain I don't even own.

How do I authorize my email marketing@mydomain.com, do I have to authorize it somewhere from my domain cpanel? Do I have to add the details somewhere on my server? Or do I need to authorize at all?

Comment: You dont need to authorize. You can basically use any dummy email id as "alias". However if you check the mail in detail, you can see that it comes from sendgrid.net domain

Answer (score 0):

You will need to go to your **sendgrid** and **generate a user/pass** within your account (you can create different credentials for different apps within 1 account).

After that, head to your laravel app and locate **config/app.php**.

Look for SMTP and activate it if necessary;

Add your new generated Sendgrid credentials to your .env if you pointed your SMTP credentials from the **config/app.php** to your .env file. Otherwise, you can add them directly to the **app.php** file instead of the **.env** **(I do not advise this as the .env file is supposed to only exist locally while app.php is shared within repositories);**

Give it a try using the MAIL service (Also for email testing and avoiding spam, I recommend [Mailtrap](https://mailtrap.io))